# Using JSF Composite Component with JBoss EAP 6.2 Modules

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, jboss-modules

How can I expose composite components to JBoss through modules? The component works correctly in the same project, the project can correctly refer to other classes within the depended on module, but attempting to use a composite component throws out an error like

```
/common/common.xhtml @30,36 <NAMESPACE:COMPONENT> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/NAMESPACE, but no tag was defined for name: COMPONENT
```

I've currently modified my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to the following, but it hasn't made any difference.

```
        <module name="deployment.CompositeComponentProject.war" export="true" meta-inf="export">
            <imports>
                <include path="**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>
```

Comment: Can you add your module.xml?

Comment: The module I'm trying to refer to is another deployment, so it doesn't have a module.xml - I can post jboss-deployment-structure?

Comment: IIRC i had a similar problem with my spring-libs and added the following to make jboss export the resources.  <resource-root path="spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar">
  <filter>
                <include path="META-INF**" />
                <include path="org**" />
            </filter>
        </resource-root>

Comment: Are you using Java9 modules? You need to export those as well. Have you got a small POC which we could check?

Comment: No Java 9 modules, running Java 1.8 - I'll put together a mini-example.